# Search list view

Tags: java, android, xml

I wanted to make my listview searchable i have putted a editText above the list i wanted when they started typing it starts filtering the text.

My list adapter

```
public class ClienteSearchListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cliente> {

protected static final String LOG_TAG = ClienteListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private List<Cliente> items;
private int layoutResourceId;
private Context context;

public ClienteSearchListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Cliente> items) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    AtomPaymentHolder holder = new AtomPaymentHolder();
    holder.cliente = items.get(position);
    holder.searchCliente = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.actionsearch_button);
    holder.searchCliente.setTag(holder.cliente);

    holder.nomecliente = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nomecliente);
    holder.ntele = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.ntelecliente);

    row.setTag(holder);

    setupItem(holder);
    return row;
}

private void setupItem(AtomPaymentHolder holder) {
    holder.nomecliente.setText(holder.cliente.getNomeCompleto());
    holder.ntele.setText(String.valueOf(holder.cliente.getNtelemovel()));
}

public static class AtomPaymentHolder {
    Cliente cliente;
    TextView nomecliente;
    TextView ntele;
    ImageButton searchCliente;
}
}
```

My activity:

```
public class search_cli extends BaseNavegationActivity {

private ClienteSearchListAdapter adapter;

List<Cliente> cliente;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_cli);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(this);
    serverRequests.FetchClienteDataInBackground(userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser(), new GetContactosCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Cliente> returnUser) {
            try {
                if (returnUser == null) {
                    throw new Exception("Não existem dados ou ocorreu um erro no servidor\nTente novamente mais tarde.");//Nao existem*
                }
                for (Cliente cliente : returnUser) {
                    adapter.add(cliente);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception erro){
                showError(erro);
            }
        }
    });

    cliente = new ArrayList<>();

    setupListViewAdapter();

}

public void actionOnClickHandler( final View v) {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        try{
            final Cliente itemToaction = (Cliente) v.getTag();
             this will do something

        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            showError();
        }
    }
}

private void setupListViewAdapter() {
    adapter = new ClienteSearchListAdapter(search_cli.this, R.layout.clientesearch, new ArrayList<Cliente>());
    ListView atomPaysListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.EnterPays_atomPaysList);
    atomPaysListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void showError(Exception ero){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Ocorreu um erro:\n" + ero.getMessage());
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
    dialogBuilder.show();
}

private void showError(){
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder=new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(search_cli.this);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Ocorreu um erro, por favor tente novamente mais tarde.");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    dialogBuilder.show();
}
}
```

my list layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
android:dividerPadding="8dp"
android:gravity="center">


<TextView android:id="@+id/nomecliente"
    style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/ntelecliente"
    style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<ImageButton android:id="@+id/actionsearch_button"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="actionOnClickHandler"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_folder_open"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:contentDescription="@string/action_search_item" /></LinearLayout>
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".search_cli"
android:id="@+id/search_cli_container"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchname"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="Pesquisar"/>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/EnterPays_atomPaysList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:listitem="@layout/clientesearch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_search_cli" >
</ListView>
```

I have found some tutorials but it didnt worked for me because i just couldnt adapt to my current code so if someone can help me would apreciate. if you are asking what does actionOnClickerHandler does ignore that it will be to go to another activity

Answer (score 0):

Add addtextchangelistener as follows:

```
// Capture Text in EditText
        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Update your adapter :

```
public class ClienteSearchListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cliente> {

protected static final String LOG_TAG = ClienteListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private List<Cliente> items;
private int layoutResourceId;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Cliente> arraylist;

public ClienteSearchListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Cliente> items) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    AtomPaymentHolder holder = new AtomPaymentHolder();
    holder.cliente = items.get(position);
    holder.searchCliente = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.actionsearch_button);
    holder.searchCliente.setTag(holder.cliente);

    holder.nomecliente = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nomecliente);
    holder.ntele = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.ntelecliente);

    row.setTag(holder);

    setupItem(holder);
    return row;
}

private void setupItem(AtomPaymentHolder holder) {
    holder.nomecliente.setText(holder.cliente.getNomeCompleto());
    holder.ntele.setText(String.valueOf(holder.cliente.getNtelemovel()));
}

public static class AtomPaymentHolder {
    Cliente cliente;
    TextView nomecliente;
    TextView ntele;
    ImageButton searchCliente;
}

public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        items.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            items.addAll(arraylist);
        } 
        else 
        {
            for (Cliente wp : arraylist) 
            {
                if (wp.getNomeCompleto.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) 
                {
                    items.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

You can update condtion 
**if(wp.getNomeCompleto.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))**
as your requirement.

Update :

```
serverRequests.FetchClienteDataInBackground(userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser(), new GetContactosCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Cliente> returnUser) {
            try {
                if (returnUser == null) {
                    throw new Exception("Não existem dados ou ocorreu um erro no servidor\nTente novamente mais tarde.");//Nao existem*
                 cliente.addAll(returnUser);
                 adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception erro){
                showError(erro);
            }
        }
    });
```

Update following method also:

```
private void setupListViewAdapter() {
    adapter = new ClienteSearchListAdapter(search_cli.this, R.layout.clientesearch, cliente);
    ListView atomPaysListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.EnterPays_atomPaysList);
    atomPaysListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: what u put in arraylist place? because it is red, sorry im very new to this do i have to put my method to get data from the server the same method to fill listview in activity?

Comment: it still cant resolve the method notifyDatasetChanged in activity and i tried without that and what you update minutes ago and when i searched it put the list empty

Comment: with your code i was not getting the result this solved my problem http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html